# Order of transactions if rollback happens

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, timestamp, rollback

I have a problem understanding what is the order of the transactions if a ROLLBACK occurs on one of the transactions.

Consider the next order of transactions from top to bottom using the TimeStamp protocol and when a transaction rollback, it will start from the beggining of its actions again.
[image]

I figured out that when T1-R(T) occurs, it will rollback because of the WTS(T) = 4.
And here is my poor understanding, what is the new order I am supposed to go by after T1 ROLLBACK?
I mean, if the rollback didn't occur then i would simply move on to the next action T3-R(N) but I fail to understand the new order to move between the actions of the transactions now.

Comment: I presume you use a sql-DBMS. R(P) means reading of Record P or is that a "for Update"? If not "for Update" What is the isolationlevel. What kind of DBMS are you using?

Comment: Yes it is an SQL DBMS, R(P) is reading the record P

Comment: Each transaction is performed in its own trajectory regardless of the other transactions

Comment: Bei aware,that indepent of running or not running transactions, reading of records might or might not have an impact on read or write operations in other transactions. MVCC Dbms Likes oracle, MySQL, Mssql normaly dont set locks. You need to cause that explicitly by formulating or generating of "select... for update " statements.